# How to make indices of a range variable in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

How to make 2 and 3600 in the following statement integer variables?

wsSource.Range("C2:C3600").Copy

So that I can have a changing range controlled by index variables like the following pseudo-statement:

wsSource.Range("Ci:Cj").Copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either:

```
wsSource.Range("C" & i & ":C" & j).Copy
```

OR

```
wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i,3),wsSource.Cells(j,3)).Copy
```

Comment: @Xander please choose one to mark as correct.  It will remove this from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @ Scott I'm new to stackoverflow. How should I mark the one as correct? I didn't see any buttons. The first one works fine for me.

Comment: There are check marks by each answer click the one by that answer you choose. It will turn green.  You can only choose one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following may work:

```
wsSource.Range("C" & i & ":C" & j).Copy
```